# I have the four sides of an irregular quadrilateral and none of its angles. How can I calculate its area?

Tags: geometry

If i have the four sides of an irregular  quadrilateral without any angle or diagonal this formula can be use for calculating of area of this triangle 
                    $A=sqr(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)$                                                        where $s=(a+b+c+d)/2$

Comment: No, in general , you need at least two pairs of opposite angles, and the orientation : what is the side length opposite each angle etc.

Comment: The four sides of a quadrilateral do not univocally determine its area, so there is no such formula.

Comment: That formula is only for quadrilaterals that are  **cyclic**.